# Maximum child elements (excessive DOM size) Google Lighthouse

Tags: html, performance, dom, frontend, lighthouse

sadly I could not find anything about that in the google documentation or on the Internet.
Maybe someone can help me, or provide me with a link, to justify a change in some DOM structure at my Job.

Our Ecommerce category menu contains a parent UL with around 300 - 400 LI's as child elements. It is common sense, that this solution (a very old template) is not very good. But I don't get the "maximum child elements" problem. I get the reduction to load less DOM Nodes for performance but even if I am changing the structure to `Ul>LI^20>UL>LI^20` There will be the even more DOM elements but no ones that exceed the "Limit" determinated by google. This would erase the maximum child nodes problem with no improvement from my knowlege.

What am I missing here ? Thanks in advance for every help.

Tried to understand the requirements but failed LOL